# Error when freeing calloc'd memory: free invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, free, calloc

I'm writing a function to get text from a file and I'm encountering an issue when I try and free some calloc'd memory.

```
ye. wee.\n
```

when a txt file with the above is passed, the function allocates memory for the 3 char characters of ye. and copies them in. Then allocates memory for the other 6 characters and copies them in. Then it prints the respective strings and frees the memory.

*testFor()* is a function that returns the index of the first '.' in a string.

I've examined the program in gdb and when it hits free(key) it causes a segfault with the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQYI7.png) (sorry, can't embed images yet).

```
//more above    
while ((fgets(line, 256, source_fp)) != NULL) {
            if (line[0] == '\n') {
                if (pflag) {
                    int first = testFor(definition);
                    int second = strlen(definition);
                    printf("%d %d\n", first, second);
                    key = calloc(first + 1, sizeof(char));
                    defn = calloc((second - (first + 1)), sizeof(char));
                    for (i = 0; i < (first + 1); i++) {
                        key[i] = definition[i];
                        }
                    int x = i + 1;
                    for (; i < second; i++) {
                        defn[i-x] = definition[i];
                        }
                    printf(">%s<\n", key);
                    printf(">%s<\n", defn);
                    free(key);
                    free(defn);
                    }
                    //more
```

I'm still new to using the memory allocation so this has me confused.

Comment: i think the for for loop is not right... you allocate three characters for key, and the you copy 3 characters from definition into it.  So, key won't be null terminated.  You need to allocate an extra character to hold the null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `defn[i-x] = definition[i];` is evaluated the first time, `x` has the value `i+1`, so `i-x` is -1.

Comment: `i - (i + 1)` is definitely -1

Comment: Yep. That's pretty embarrassing on my part. As a matter of clutter control, should I remove this question considering that it's rather unlikely someone would find this useful?

Comment: I'd leave it, since maybe someone might make a similar mistake